# Using LINQ to SQL to read stored procedures

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

Does anyone know a way to access the text of stored procedures using LINQ to SQL? I'd like to audit a set of stored procedures to check that they contain all contain some common code.

It feels like there should be a nice way of opening them through a LINQ to SQL data context but I don't know how. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do this through LINQ in the first place?

Comment: Just because I'm already using LINQ to do other things in this project, so if I can do everything through the same connection then my life becomes much easier. I agree that LINQ isn't the ideal way to do this from scratch though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something along these lines:

```
string results = db.ExecuteQuery<string>
(@"EXEC sp_helptext '{0}'", procedure_name);
```

or use this query in you LINQ:

```
SELECT text
FROM syscomments
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'procedure_name')
ORDER BY colid
```

Comment: As an aside, note that executequery can be parameterised: (@"EXEC sp_helptext {0}", procedureName);

Comment: Incidentally (in case anyone else needs to do this), the ExecuteQuery method seems to return an IEnumberable<string> so I've ended up converting it to a List<string> in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using SQL Server.

To retrieve the text of an stored procedure you will need to execute the [sp_helptext](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176112.aspx) system stored procedure.

To know how to execute an stored procedure from Linq you can see [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that is a task ideally suited to LINQ-to-SQL - but you can presumably get the text from things like [`syscomments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260393(SQL.80).aspx) - however, this could be obfuscated. I would run the tests again my code repository instead of the database, personally.